# statistics, how to solve this problem

Tags: statistics

Two players, who have equal chances of winning each round, compete for a money prize. The first player to
win three rounds collects the total amount.
(a) If the game is interrupted when the score was 2 to 1, how should the players divide the stakes fairly?
(b) What if the game was interrupted when the score was 1 to 0?

Comment: See Pascal's Triangle and see binomial distribution.

Comment: This is the Pascal/Fermat [problem of points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_points).  What have you tried? In particular, (a) can easily be done in your head